# select divs with a class and do something to the clicked div

Tags: jquery, css

i am trying to click on a `div` with a class `informationHov`
and change color of div and want rest `divs` with same class do remove color.

how do i select the divs with same class which are not clicked.
i mean suppose i click the second div of same class and how to select the other divs with same class and do something to them and not the second div?
is there any  `$(this).not('.informationHov').css('')`
Something like that....
Thanks.

Comment: generally best to toggle a class, simpler to undo than inline css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this very quickly, by:

1. Remove / reset the color on all divs with the class `informationHov`

   `$('.informationHov').css({color:notClicked});`
2. Set the color for the clicked div:

   `$(this).css({color:clicked});`

With that in mind, you would likely be best to apply (`addClass`)/remove (`removeClass`) a CSS class, to give solid separation of concerns, and not change the styling in your Javascript directly.

As you note in your comments, if you have additional things you want to do with the other items, simply select them all and exclude the currently clicked item from that collection by using [`.not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

`$('.informationHov').not($(this))`

```js
$('.informationHov').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $('.informationHov').not(this).each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    /// do something to all other elements
  });
});
```

```css
.informationHov {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.active {
  background-color: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="informationHov">One</div>
<div class="informationHov">Two</div>
<div class="informationHov">Three</div>
```

Comment: i mean i have to do a lot on remianing divs not just color change. how can i select the remaining divs?

Comment: can pass `this` directly to `not()` without wrapping in `$()`

Comment: There's no need for the `.each`, `.removeClass()` will operate on all the elements returned by `.not(this)`

Comment: @Jamiec - the OP says he wishes to perform more actions as well as removing classes, `each` allows for this (assuming the actions arent chainable etc). Simply using `removeClass` is also noted in the above

Answer (score 2):

In direct response to the question, yes there is a `not(this)` option:

```js
$('.test').click(function() {
  $(this).css({
    'color': 'red'
  });
  $('.test').not(this).css({
    'color': 'blue'
  });
});
```

```css
.test {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">Test</div>
<div class="test">Test</div>
<div class="test">Test</div>
<div class="test">Test</div>
<div class="test">Test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```js
$('.informationHov').on('click',function(){
    $(this).addClass('clicked').siblings().removeClass('clicked')
});
```

```css
.informationHov{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border: 1px solid black
}

.clicked{
    background-color:blue  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="informationHov">One</div>
<div class="informationHov">Two</div>
<div class="informationHov">Three</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The siblings() method returns all sibling elements of the selected element
check this : 
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_traversing_siblings

and I've created a fiddle for your question:
http://jsfiddle.net/r4utzkqy/`r4utzkqy`